# Reference the action field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, attributes

How can I refference and then assign a new value to the text in the action field via JavaScript?

```
<form name="submitForm" action="THIS_TEXT">
    <input type="submit" class="button">See Results</input>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference your `form` by name `document.forms["submitForm"]` then use `setAttribute()` function to set new text to the attribute you want :

```
document.forms["submitForm"].setAttribute("action", "new_text_here");
```

**NOTE :** Then `input` is a ***self-closing*** tag, so your `input` button should be like :

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="See Result"/>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.forms["submitForm"].setAttribute("action", "new_text_here"); //set action

console.log(document.forms["submitForm"].getAttribute("action")); //get action
```

```html
<form name="submitForm" action="THIS_TEXT">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="See Result"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This assuming you only have one form with the name submitForm. If you have multiple forms on the page, you should give them an id and use `document.getElementById` instead.

```js
$forms = document.getElementsByName("submitForm");
$form = $forms[0];

$form.setAttribute("action", "NEW ACTION");
```

```html
<form name="submitForm" action="THIS_TEXT">
    <input type="submit" class="button">See Results</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try in such a way also.

`<form name="submitForm"  action="THIS_TEXT">
    <input type="submit" class="button">See Results</input>
</form>`

And now javascript

```
 $('form[name="submitForm"]').attr('action','revised_action_url');
```

Comment: Be careful, there's no jQuery tag in the OP.